# Does python socket basically connect host and client over internet like a computer to computer VPN?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, connection, vpn

I searched about this a lot but I could not find anything. I haven't tried much with **python sockets**, just made a system where a host and a client can message each other. What I want to know is when a client is connected to a host via python socket, does it make a connection **outside the program** too? Like can we play any lan game after being connected via sockets for example ??

Comment: Yes, it's a TC/IP socket like any other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sockets are not specific to any language; they are the logical endpoint offered by the underlying API to the userspace. You can create TCP/IP sockets in any language which supports networking.

*"What I want to know is when a client is connected to a host via python socket, does it make a connection outside the program too?"*

That depends on which layer you are looking at. Consider the first three layers of the TCP/IP model from the top (Application, Transport, Network).

- Application Layer:  All the underlying of the internet are abstracted from the Application layer. Now, if you see whether a connection is established outside your program, that purely depends on what protocol they are following. If you consider HTTP protocol, it is mostly stateless or connectionless (If cookies are ignored). But if you look at SSL, some handshakes happen, and the session state is maintained in both the client-side and server-side.
- Transport Layer: The two famous protocols in this layer are TCP and UDP. With TCP before any data transfer, a TCP connection is established by performing a three-way handshake. But in the case of UDP, no such term like a connection is defined.
- Internet Layer: Though the well known and most commonly used network architecture is the Internet, there are some other architectures like ATM CBR and ATM ABR. The Internet architecture falls under the category of datagram networks, meaning there is no state maintained, the link-layer switches, or routers just forward the packets. In contrast, ATM architecture falls under the category of Virtual-circuit networks. Each connection at the network layer is monitored to deliver the services. e.g., in the case of ATM CBR, the connections are monitored to deliver a constant bit rate service, and in the case of ATM ABR, the connections are monitored to deliver a minimum bit rate service.

Here I just summarized the connection setup for the first three layers, and the same things can happen with the other layers as well.

To conclude, whether the connection is established outside your programs? It depends on all these above factors, what application layer protocol you are using, what transport layer protocol you are using, and what is the underlying network architecture... etc. And you can also see a scenario where the connection establishment happens at the network layer but not in the application layer, that's where all these network abstractions come. You can blissfully ignore the underlying details!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation ! Let's say I have two python scripts, and the connection is established over UDP. And the system is designed in a way that the server script waits till a particular string message is received from the client script before closing the socket. In the meantime, till I have not sent that particular message from the client script, the connection is still running. Would I be able to let's say play a lan multiplayer game like CS GO with the server and client?

Comment: Your question is more focused until the point you talk about playing the game. First of all, there is nothing like connection in UDP protocol. Let us just take TCP and talk. Machines these days are mutliprocess capable. If the system is capable of just making one connection at a time then it means we are in stone age. The system can make multiple connections at a time; the number is theoretical limited by supported protocols and port count. And coming to gaming part, I dont know what mechanism CSGO adopts. But I believe it uses UDP.  >>

Comment: Now, let says CSGO uses a default UDP port of 56756, and if your server or client is binded to that port then you are disabling that particular node's CSGO to communicate with other nodes CSGO. But if CSGO is smart and if it can manage the communications by using ephemeral ports then it can manage even if your  client and server is running.

Comment: Thanks it explains !